# I am getting javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not extract result set metadata in select query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, metadata

```
public List<Object> MerTxnDetailsReportCsv() {
    
    
    EntityManager entityManager = JPAUtility.getEntityManager();
    List<Object> auditList = null;
    try {
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                "select payee_account from txn_history_upi_fin WHERE TRUNC(trn_date_time,'DD') = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1, 'DD') and payee_account is not null group by payee_account");

        auditList = query.getResultList();
          logger.info(auditList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in MerTxnDetailsReportCsv : " + e);
        logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (null != entityManager)
                entityManager.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.error("Exception in MerTxnDetailsReportCsv : " + e1);
        }
    }
    return auditList;
}
```

I am trying to fetch account details through select query using entitymanager but getting the exception.

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you to use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` for better native query

and the codes :

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> MerTxnDetailsReportCsv() {
    var query = "select payee_account from txn_history_upi_fin " +
            "WHERE TRUNC(trn_date_time,'DD') = TRUNC(SYSDATE-1, 'DD') " +
            "and payee_account is not null group by payee_account";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
}
```